# Typescript abstract class extend from mixin(class, generic) / mixin(class A, class B | class D...)

Tags: typescript, class, generics, abstract, extends

I recently ran into a problem and I can't figure out the solution from other questions.
So basically what I would like to achieve is:

I have a lot of abstract classes, and I have to create more abstract classes that extends from the others such as this:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass extends Mixin(A, B | C | D)
```

where Mixin is a function from the ts-mixer npm package
and A is an abstract class that won't change, it stays the same, however the other class is not known specifically.

I tried it with generics with no luck, I tried creating a factory function, but I can't return an abstract class like this

```
return abstract class MyAbstractClass extends Mixin(A, param){}
```

only a non-abstract class.

If somebody could provide an answer or point me in the right direction I would appreciate it

edit: What I'm currently doing is:

```
abstract class Button{
    abstract onToggle():void
}

abstract class A{
    abstract foo():void
}
abstract class B{
    abstract bar():void
}

abstract class ExtendedButtonA extends Mixin(Button, A){}
abstract class ExtendedButtonB extends Mixin(Button, B){}
```

So when I make the final class I have to do it like this:

```
class FinalButtonA extends ExtendedButtonA{}
class FinalButtonB extends ExtendedButtonB{}
```

What I want to be able to do:

```
class FinalButton extends ExtendedButton<A>{}
```

or something like this.

Comment: @jcalz I updated the question with some code, I hope it's more understandable. 
*Mixin* is an npm package from here: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mixer)
B | C | D meant to mean class B or class C or class D etc.. Not as in a union. Always only one is used, but it is not known which one until the final class is being created

Comment: @jcalz, I can only try this out tomorrow, but this looks very promising, I think is it, thank you.

Comment: @jcalz I managed to get hold of someone to try it out, the solution seems to be working. Would you mind posting it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is write the `ExtendedButton` factory function like this:

```
function ExtendedButton<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => InstanceType<T>>(
  ctor: T
) {
  return Mixin(Button, ctor);
}
```

This seems to work for your example code:

```
abstract class A {
  abstract foo(): void
}

abstract class FinalButton extends ExtendedButton(A) { }

function foo(fb: FinalButton) {
  fb.foo();
  fb.onToggle();
}
```

---

The way I did this was to first see what happens when you call `Mixin(Button, A)` directly:

```
const testA = Mixin(Button, A)
// const testA: Class<any[], Button & A, typeof Button & typeof A, false>
```

And then compare it to a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) version where instead of `A` we pass in a `ctor` value of a generic [abstract construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-construct-signatures) type:

```
function ExtendedButton<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => object>(
  ctor: T
) {
  return Mixin(Button, ctor);
}

const testA2 = ExtendedButton(A);
// const testA2: Class<any[], Button & object, typeof Button & typeof A, false>
```

The difference here is that the second type argument is `Button & object` instead of the desired `Button & A`.  Why is that?  It seems that the compiler is widening the constructor to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `abstract new (...args: any) => object` and getting its instance type, prematurely widening all the way to `object` when we wanted `A`.

Well, if it's going to use that constraint, maybe we can make the constraint itself generic, so that it's still useful. Given a constructorlike type `T`, we can use [the `InstanceType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) to express its instance type.  So let's change `object` to `InstanceType<T>`:

```
function ExtendedButton<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => InstanceType<T>>(
  ctor: T
) {
  return Mixin(Button, ctor);
}
```

Luckily that compiles (sometimes recursive constraints don't), and now the call signature looks like

```
// function ExtendedButton<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => InstanceType<T>>(
//   ctor: T
// ): Class<any[], Button & InstanceType<T>, typeof Button & T, false>
```

where the second type parameter is `Button & InstanceType<T>`.  Let's try it out:

```
const testA3 = ExtendedButton(A);
// const testA3: Class<any[], Button & A, typeof Button & typeof A, false>
```

Perfect, that's the same type as what we get if we call `Mixin` directly.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgtgDg9gTgFwAQG8kFkwA8wDskC+SAZnDBEgOQIDOAtBNgKZyUDcooAhgEY0JwuAY2RCANlxo0kAIQCuCBDHwpQSJL36CRSZQBUYAc0NimACgCUALiQA3GGAAmoApxCaBw0RKlIAgqhqGnyeOsQwMJY29k4u3CHa3pLSMoEg6h6JSDxccFF2Ds4griCgxHK4ImDKSACiWAhMuI5MjvKKygA8ekhMDU2O0pleSLhMAO5IZgB0s7mGNDZcuACeFkgAvAB8SACSuPzLQkx6K1BM3VtbZkEi8DZ6oOuq6UhwTAhycPiYOLhm7SUuAANEg7nALBxiqAAPQwkgVKo1eqNZqtQFdHp9VGDYJaEZjSYzOZwBZLVbrbZ7A4II4nM4XPRXG4gOHqMFKOAPWHw6xIADCPhonWWKwA2gBdUEY-AAMmph0q9POl1BCAZMGIsgUQKQ8r0oOIXDENCYWzc8XxOnEySQADE8MaZb1+s1pCiBuidcozH5noQyoiENV8OFIsQeDYHbgnd7cM8ghHpmHLFD1En9EYTOZIXFSvnQEJlPwkI1+AENhhsHgAXHQX6eWDi8gywg-DZBckRatJdK43r-GqNVrnfL1edNYOSMbTeb8+VKsHka6Wm04wB5OBgQzdF04oYJAkTKazabzRYaCmbHYwHgAKyYImut053JACde70+3yrf1rHRBDl4FzaFWXhBckXwD00TXADd2xAYDytZBCRPEkyUvNZr0w58wPZcE3zZPlOykbtxSlbUAIHW8HxEIcJxHft9UNGczULZtSyYcsACZNjqFcvQAzdt19EC2SLGlOJ4jshTI3tKN1eUaMfBB6KYSdR1LYcpyNE02PzCSS1bPwAGY+Og1cZVEqFxI44yTJkrtRXkzS-DUjSmK0hidNYrYgA)